# ACE string specifying the current user

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I'm trying to set up the permissions on a named pipe the 'correct' way.

It seems that the easiest correct way to set access permissions is through an ACE string, like this:

```
sa.nLength        = sizeof(sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(aceStr,
                                                        SDDL_REVISION_1,
                                                        &(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor),
                                                        NULL))
{
  pipe = CreateNamedPipe(..., &sa);
}
```

I want the pipe owner to have full control, and everyone else to have read and write access only. I also want the pipe to have a low integrity level so that low integrity level clients can connect.

In the past I've always just used a NULL DACL because it is easy, but Microsoft clearly state this is not a good idea because it allows any client to take full ownership of the pipe.

I know the SADL part of the string needs to be

```
S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)
```

which gives the pipe an integrity level of low.

The DACL part needs to include

```
D:(A;;FRFW;;;WD)
```

which gives 'Everyone' read and write access. I need to append another ACE string onto the end of this to set full control for the owner. But I can't find a code that goes in the final position for Windows to replace it with the SID of the current process.

```
S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)D:(A;;FRFW;;;WD)(A;;FA;;;<current process?>)
```

I found some code that gets the SID of the current process, but it involves a succession of about 4 or 5 API calls. This ought to be a trivial task, so I'm certain that is not the right way to do what I want.

Finally, am I even remotely on the right track? Why is this so complicated?

Two supplementary questions: Must the security attributes structure passed to CreateNamedPipe() have the same lifetime as the pipe or can you delete it as soon as the call returns? Can you use the same structure for more than one pipe instance, or does CreateNamedPipe() modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my question was based on my confusion and misunderstanding.

The owner of a file *always* has permission to change the file's permissions.

So I do not need explicitly to set permissions for the owner. The ACE string I needed was:

```
S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)D:(A;;FRFW;;;WD)
```

(The reason I wanted to set permissions explicitly for the owner was that I thought if I didn't do this then the owner would effectively lose ownership.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `CO` ([creator owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379602%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is the closest match.

Comment: Unfortunately, `CO` doesn't work here. `CO` comes into effect when you create a child object. (It says "When you inherit this rule, then put the creator/owner's SID here.") But it doesn't apply to the object itself.

Comment: @Raymond: I read that about CO. Would PS (Principal Self) work? I'm guessing not because when I try it, the ACE reads back as PS, and all processes are 'self' to themselves... And when I look at the security settings for random files I have, none of them are owned by SELF.